# Can I be notified when a content type is added to a list in 2010?

Tags: content-type

Not too much to add, but I'd like to be notified of when a content type has been added or removed from the content types associated with a list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are no straight forward methods to accomplish this, because there are no events triggered when a content type is added or removed. You can also only attach workflows to items for specific content types.

Event handlers and workflows can only be created or associated to ***items*** on a list. Using [SPWorkflowAssociation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowassociation_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method, you can associate workflows to specific content types. But even these workflows are triggered, when items are added or removed to the list.